# How does one receive forgiveness from someone they have wronged after their death?

Tags: death, sin, kaparah-atonement

Say you sinned against a fellow Jew. You decide you want to seek forgiveness from that person but then discover that person has passed away. G-d forgives sins against Him but man must seek forgiveness from his fellow man. How does one receive forgiveness from his fellow man posthumously?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.606.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> אם מת אשר חטא לו מביא עשרה בני אדם ומעמידם על קברו ואומר חטאתי לאלהי
>   ישראל ולפלוני זה שחטאתי לו (ונהגו לבקש מחילה בערב יו"כ
>
> If the person against whom he sinned has died, then he brings 10
>   people with him to stand by his grave and he says: "I have sinned
>   before the G-d of Israel and against So-and-So I have transgressed."
>   (Remah: And our custom is to request forgiveness on the eve of Yom
>   Kippur (Mordekhai)).

Comment: Nice, and see the bottom of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91754/11501

Comment: Excellent answer and source. Thank you פרי זהב.